# How do I average 20 saved ANN model?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have created 20 neural network models with the exact same architecture (but different seed numbers) and I have saved them as SM1, SM2, …., SM20. I am basically tying to import these models using the joblib function and use the average model (called NN here) to apply for various analyses. When I run this in Jupyter Notebook , I get the following error. Appreciate any help.

```
NN1  = joblib.load('SM1.sav')
NN2  = joblib.load('SM2.sav')
NN3  = joblib.load('SM3.sav')
NN4  = joblib.load('SM4.sav')
NN5  = joblib.load('SM5.sav')
NN6  = joblib.load('SM6.sav')
NN7  = joblib.load('SM7.sav')
NN8  = joblib.load('SM8.sav')
NN9  = joblib.load('SM9.sav')
NN10  = joblib.load('SM10.sav')
NN11  = joblib.load('SM11.sav')
NN12  = joblib.load('SM12.sav')
NN13  = joblib.load('SM13.sav')
NN14  = joblib.load('SM14.sav')
NN15  = joblib.load('SM15.sav')
NN16  = joblib.load('SM16.sav')
NN17  = joblib.load('SM17.sav')
NN18  = joblib.load('SM18.sav')
NN19  = joblib.load('SM19.sav')
NN20  = joblib.load('SM20.sav')

NN    = (NN1+NN2+NN3+NN4+NN5+NN6+NN7+NN8+NN9+NN10+NN11+NN12+NN13+NN14+NN15+NN16+NN17+NN18+NN19+NN20)/(20)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MLPRegressor' and 'MLPRegressor'

Comment: you don't average the model but average the predictions those models make

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought since the structure of the ANN is the same for all 20 cases with the same number of neurons (except different seed numbers), the weights and biases can be averaged to get one model.